Sympy: How can I add a symbolic custom matrix function?
I'm using sympy matrix expressions for differentiation and I want to add some custom functions matrix functions and including spectral norm and eigenvectors. I also want to be able to differentiate expressions containing these functions.
The relevant documentation(https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/custom-functions.html) says "functions that accept or return other kinds of objects than complex numbers should subclass another class, such as Boolean, MatrixExpr, Expr, or Basic." but only gives examples for Function.
Later it says "Subclasses of Expr that aren’t Function subclasses will need to define _eval_derivative()"
I have three questions relating to this

When I subclass MatrixExpr what does _eval_derivative need to do?
Do I need to define/hook/set/etc. anything else
Does anyone have an example I could read?

I tried searching the sympy documentation and code for relavent information and didn't find anything useful.
